# Gerund and infinitive dispfference

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

> 1)I don’t remember of meeting you in kashmir last year.
>
> 2)I don’t remember meeting you in kashmir last year.
>
> 3)I don’t remember to have met you in kashmir last year

Which of the three sentences is correct? What is the difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 is correct.  The others do not really mean anything, they just read like broken attempts at number 2.